# Incorrect reference element signature XML C#

Tags: c#, xml, signature, xml-signature

I need to implement the EBICS Protocol, particulary the HPB request and i need to sign my XML File :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ebicsNoPubKeyDigestsRequest xmlns="http://www.ebics.org/H003" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ebics.org/H003 http://www.ebics.org/H003/ebics_keymgmt_request.xsd" Version="H003" Revision="1">
  <header authenticate="true">
    <static>
      <HostID>EBIXQUAL</HostID>
      <Nonce>234AB2340FD2C23035764578FF3091C1</Nonce>
      <Timestamp>2015-11-13T10:32:30.123Z</Timestamp>
      <PartnerID>AD598</PartnerID>
      <UserID>EF056</UserID>
      <OrderDetails>
        <OrderType>HPB</OrderType>
        <OrderAttribute>DZHNN</OrderAttribute>
      </OrderDetails>
      <SecurityMedium>0000</SecurityMedium>
    </static>
    <mutable />
  </header>
</ebicsNoPubKeyDigestsRequest>
```

So i need to sign the elements where

> authenticate="true"

To sign my document in C# i wrote this code :

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
        xmlDoc.Load("hpbtest.xml");
        RSA Key = new GestionCertificat("CN=XML_ENC_TEST_CERT4").getClePrivee();
        // Create a SignedXml object.
        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
        // Add the key to the SignedXml document.
        signedXml.SigningKey = Key;
        // Create a reference to be signed.
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.Uri = "#xpointer(//*[@authenticate='true'])";
        // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
        XmlDsigExcC14NTransform env = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform();
        reference.AddTransform(env);
        // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);
        // Compute the signature.
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();
        // Get the XML representation of the signature and save
        // it to an XmlElement object.
        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
        // Append the element to the XML document.
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
        xmlDoc.Save("hpbtest.xml");
```

But when i try to sign it, i get this error on line

> signedXml.ComputeSignature()

:

> Incorrect reference element

Could you help me to solve my problem please ?

Thank you in advance !

Thomas !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reverse engineered the XPointer operations by SignedXml and Reference classes and.. I can give you all the details in a seperate answer, but what I conclude for now is, you can only have two types of queries:

```
#xpointer(/)
```

This works because it is explicitly checked for, and

```
#xpointer(id(
```

This is again explicitly (with string.StartsWith) checked.

Therefore, the only way to achieve this, as you pointed out in your comment, seems like to extend the SignedXml class and to override the GetIdElement method as follows:

```
public class CustomSignedXml : SignedXml
{
    XmlDocument xmlDocumentToSign;

    public CustomSignedXml(XmlDocument xmlDocument) : base(xmlDocument)
    {
        xmlDocumentToSign = xmlDocument;
    }

    public override XmlElement GetIdElement(XmlDocument document, string idValue)
    {
        XmlElement matchingElement = null;
        try
        {
            matchingElement = base.GetIdElement(document, idValue);
        }
        catch (Exception idElementException)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(idElementException.ToString());
        }

        if (matchingElement == null)
        {
            // at this point, idValue = xpointer(//*[@authenticate='true'])
            string customXPath = idValue.TrimEnd(')');
            customXPath = customXPath.Substring(customXPath.IndexOf('(') + 1);
            matchingElement = xmlDocumentToSign.SelectSingleNode(customXPath) as XmlElement;
        }

        return matchingElement;
    }
}
```

Then in the consumer code, just change the SignedXml to CustomSignedXml:

```
CustomSignedXml signedXml = new CustomSignedXml(xmlDoc);
```

Comment: The Ebics protocol don't accept the id attribute on the header element so i can't use your solution

Comment: Oh sorry for that because I mostly stated the problem and the only way around, as from deep as my research got me.

Comment: Do you think I can Override `GetIdElement`to select the good nodes with `#xpointer(//*[@authenticate='true')]` ? 
But I have no idea where I can do it

Comment: Yes. The SignedXml class is not sealed and the method is virtual. Extend SignedXml class and override this method then you can test the base method in a try catch block and if it fails or returns null you can find the xml element and return it

Comment: I can add that to my answer if you have an hour

Comment: Then here it is. Edited my answer. I also realized the motive behind the original implementation of SignedXml class. It SHOULD return a single node. It is therefore looking for the entire document element by (/), or a single element with id='***'. Signing multiple elements is not possible in one shot as far as I can see.

Comment: After a test matchingElement is null

Comment: With your xml document, I got that matching element? name='header'

Comment: How did you do that test? You just need to change that SignedXml to CustomSignedXml. What is the idValue when the code is in overridden GetIdElement method?

Comment: Sorry it works, i forgot to change id="header" in authenticate="true"